# Passing zend error controller extra paramters

Tags: php, zend-framework

I am attempting to provide user friendly error messages via my web application for certain errors. I want to be able to pass the throw exception call and extra paramter, such like "USER" so the error controller gives this paramter to the view and displays a different style page with maybe a more friendly color and a meaningful message, but I can't figure out how to pass extra arguments. Here is the current setup:

Some check in one of the controllers:

```
throw new Zend_Controller_Exception("User not found",403);
```

Error controller (ErrorController.php):

```
class ErrorController
    extends Zend_Controller_Action
    {
        public function errorAction()
        {
        $errors = $this->_getParam('error_handler');
        switch ($errors->type) {
```

etc.

So I want to be able to do like:

```
$this->view->type = $this->_getParam('type');
```

in the controller, so I can do this in the view:

```
if($this->type == "USER") {
    some css stuff
    echo $this->exception;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds like you could:

1. Create a custom exception class (`My_Exception_UserFriendly` or the like) that accepts your other parameters
2. In a controller (or elsewhere) throw this exception with your custom params, and
3. Use an `instanceof` check in your `ErrorController` to populate your view variables.

And, as you already note, make sure your view checks for the presence of that user-friendly data before attempting to render it.

**Update**

Actually, reading more closely, it doesn't look like you need the exception to carry any additional information. Simple creating a custom class should be sufficient for your detection/rendering purposes.

You can create an empty (!) exception class in `library/My/Exception/UserFiendly.php`:

```
class My_Exception_UserFriendly extends Exception
{
}
```

Then when you encounter an error that you would like to show to the user in a friendly way, just throw an exception of this type:

```
if ($rainyDay){
    throw new My_Exception_UserFriendly('Seeing some inclement weather, I\'m afraid');
}
```

Then in your `ErrorController::errorAction()`:

```
$exception = $this->_getParam('error_handler')->exception;
if ($exception instanceof My_Exception_UserFriendly){
    $this->view->friendlyErrorMessage = $exception->getMessage();
}
```

Finally, down in your view-script `error/error.phtml`:

```
<?php if ($this->friendlyErrorMessage): ?>
<h2>With Humble Apologies, Valued User</h2>
<p><?= $this->escape($this->friendlyErrorMessage) ?></p>
<?php endif; ?>
```

In fact, some would argue that the *specific message* we render is purely a *view consideration*. In that case, you could create a custom exception - perhaps extending this generic `UserFriendly` exception - for *each* friendly message you wish to support. Then in your `ErrorController`, detect the specific sub-type and set a key in the view identifying that subtype. Then, in the view, render the specific friendly message corresponding to the given key. Might be overkill just for the sake of purity, but throwing it out there for those who value those considerations.

Comment: I'm not sure how I create a custome exception class which can accept extra arguement, could you provide an example?
Do I just create another class extending Zend_Controller_Action? Also I missed off the extending Zend_Controller_Action from my question, don't know if that changes anything!

Comment: Sorry only just noticed this update, this is exactly what I want, thanks! Perhaps a custom exception for each time is overkill, but with the growth of the application in may be useful to implement!